# process.env variables always undefined, works perfectly fine in other project

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, cypress

Project A (working):

```
cy.request(`${Cypress.env('mainnet')}api?module=account&action=txlist&address=${ethWallet}&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page=1&offset=10&sort=asc&apikey=${process.env.apiKey}`).then((response) => {
```

.env File:

```
apiKey=YOUR_KEY_HERE
```

Project B (not working):

```
const key = process.env.apiKey
const token = process.env.authToken

Cypress.Commands.add('createBoard', (name) => {
    cy
      .request('POST', 'boards', { name, key: process.env.apiKey, token: process.env.authToken })
      .then(({ body }) => {
        Cypress.env('boards').push(body)
      })
  })
```

.env File:

```
apiKey=MY_KEY
authToken=MY_TOKEN
```

Both projects have the same packages and a correct .env file setup. So why in project B do I keep getting undefined? It makes no sense at all.

Comment: It's not really a good question. Is it accessing `process.env.apiKey` that's a problem or the request itself? You can easily reconcile which part is failing, then narrow down your question.

Comment: The problem is it is undefined when accessed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's always `undefined` in the test is because `process` is a nodejs object. It's not available in the browser where the tests are running.

There's two ways to use a `dotenv` file with Cypress though:

1. Use the plugin [`cypress-dotenv` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-dotenv) and it'll map your nodejs `.env` file vars to the Cypress env variables.
2. Map them manually in the `plugins/index.js` file:

```js
require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  config.env.apiKey = process.env.apiKey
  config.env.authToken = process.env.authToken
  return config
}
```